# Adding JQueryMobile Dialog functionality to PhotoSwipe footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, photoswipe

Trying to get a jQueryMobile Dialog to open up upon the clicking of an option in a PhotoSwipe footer.

I'm using the following code:

```
                 options = {
                    enableMouseWheel: true,
                        enableKeyboard: true, 
                        getToolbar: function(){
                            return '<div class="ps-toolbar-close" style="padding-top: 12px;">Close</div><div class="ps-toolbar-play" style="padding-top: 12px;">Play</div><div class="ps-toolbar-previous" style="padding-top: 12px;">Previous</div><div class="ps-toolbar-next" style="padding-top: 12px;">Next</div><a onclick="" href="pages.aspx" data-role="button" data-icon="grid" data-transition="slidedown" data-iconpos="bottom">Pages</a>';
                        }
                    };


                    myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe(options);
```

But when I click "Pages", nothing happens, Firebug is reporting that it's loading the page via JSON and not actually rendering it.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it's being loaded underneath the Photoswipe modal. If you inspect the Photoswipe modal you'll probably see that it's z-index is set super high (500+). The jQuery Mobile dialog would have to have a higher z-index than Photoswipe for you to see it.